# Network connection problems using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my API file:

```
public class Api {

    //public static final String BASE_URL="http://tfg_test/";
    //public static final String BASE_URL="http://192.168.68.108/"; //192.168.68.108   10.0.2.2
    public static final String BASE_URL="http://192.168.68.108/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApi(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And here`s my apiservice call:

```
@GET("api/students/{id}")
    Call<Alumno> getStudent(@Path("id") int id);
```

And here´s how I do the call in my activity:

```
alumnoCall.enqueue(new Callback<Alumno>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Alumno> call, Response<Alumno> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Alumno alumno=response.body();
                   /*Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "El servidor retornó datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    tv1.setText("Bienvenido "+alumno.getName());

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "El servidor retornó un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Alumno> call, Throwable t) {
                if(t instanceof IOException){
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "Problema de conversión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

I get a connection error because the toast message is: "Error de conexión".
If I look at the logcat I see this:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
2023-05-17 12:57:05.965  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:143)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.965  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:162)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.968  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:335)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.970  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.970  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.973  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.973  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.974  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.974  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.975  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.983  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.984  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.985  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.985  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.986  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.986  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.986  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.986  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.987  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.989  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.989  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.992  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.993  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.996  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2023-05-17 12:57:05.996  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.996  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
2023-05-17 12:57:05.996  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:90)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.000  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:129)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.003  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      ... 20 more
2023-05-17 12:57:06.023  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
2023-05-17 12:57:06.023  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:143)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.024  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:162)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.027  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:335)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.028  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.028  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.028  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.030  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.039  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.039  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.039  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.043  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.043  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.043  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.043  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.044  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.045  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.046  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.046  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.053  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.053  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.054  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.054  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.054  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.055  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2023-05-17 12:57:06.057  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.057  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.058  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:90)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.058  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:129)
2023-05-17 12:57:06.058  5080-5080  System.err              com.example.tfgsmartwatch            W      ... 20 more
```

But I don´t know what error could be. I thought it could be because of my URL_base ip but I have wirtten my pc ip.
Thank you very much.